# Evolution of parasite into ideal parasite

Tags: ecology, natural-selection, population-biology

An ideal parasite is a parasite which thrives within a host without harming it (according to my NCERT textbook).

Then, quite obviously, why hasn't that happened yet? I mean, natural selection can lead to such a species, which is beneficial to us and also, not at all detrimental to the parasite.

Comment: It has happened, many times; commensal and mutualistic species are common.  Mitochondria and chloroplasts, lichens, etc are examples.   But there is no specific reason, other than common misunderstandings of natural selection, to expect this to be inevitable.  You may want to explain your reasoning for that point (or put it as a separate question).

Comment: @iayork You are right. However, how are mitochondria and chloroplasts examples of ideal parasite? Also, which point are you asking me to explain?

Comment: Do you understand the current understanding of how [mitochondria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrion#Origin) and [chloroplasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroplast#Cyanobacterial_ancestor) arose? If so, please clarify why they don't fit your question.  If not, check wikipedia, linked above. The other point I suggest you explain separately  is your claim about evolution, which I believe indicates a misunderstanding of natural selection.

Comment: @iayork Yes, I didn't know about the current understanding on how chloroplast and mitochondria arose, so that's clear now. Also, edited the question!

Comment: Why are you asking why something didn't happen, then, when as you can see it has happened many times?  Is there more to your question?

Comment: @iayork I knew such species existed, but didn't think of them as an ideal parasite. Because, when you think of a parasite, lichen, mitochondria and chloroplasts are not the first things to come to your mind. You opened up my mind :D

Comment: @iayork I think you can make an answer by developing further your comment.

Comment: Related: [Why do parasites sometimes kill their hosts?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/why-do-parasites-sometimes-kill-their-hosts)

Comment: There was a recent opinion article in science which hypothesizes that mitochondria and chloroplasts could have been parasites. In my opinion, the paper has a lot of incorrect presuppositions and also makes far-fetched assumptions. IMO, mitochondria and chloroplasts would have been preys and not parasites. Anyway, an ideal parasite is the one that survives anything. What your textbook says is one possible way by which it can do that. You should see the post that @Remi.b mentioned.

Comment: Post is related to [Why do parasites sometimes kill their hosts?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/why-do-parasites-sometimes-kill-their-hosts) and I think duplicate of [Why have parasites not evolved to be harmless?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41617/why-have-parasites-not-evolved-to-be-harmless).