# Have people in Africa already started evolving resistance to AIDS?

Tags: evolution, cell-biology, immunology, human-evolution

Are people living in areas where AIDS is rampant (for e.g. Africa), less likely to die from it than they once were because some of the people without genes/mutations that give them resistance already died off?

Is there any data on this?

Comment: HIV-resistence is indeed a thing (see [Pancino et al., 2010](http://jid.oxfordjournals.org/content/202/Supplement_3/S345.full) for example).

Comment: You seem to focus on African populations but there are non-african countries that have quite a high HIV prevalence too such as Jamaica, Haiti, Russia or Ukraine. Generally speaking, the highest prevalence are in southern Africa (Swaziland, Bostwana, South Africa, Namibia, Lesotho, etc..) though. Swaziland has the highest world-wide prevalence with an impressive frequency of 26.5% of the 19-42 years old people being infected ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_HIV/AIDS_adult_prevalence_rate))

Comment: Your comments on parasite evolution are wrong and your question is therefore opinion-based. Highest resistance will not select for lowest virulence. You might want to read on the subject. Here are two related posts on Biology.SE: [Viruses selected by evolution](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/why-do-parasites-sometimes-kill-their-hosts) (which is a horrible title btw) and [Why do parasites sometimes kill their hosts?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/why-do-parasites-sometimes-kill-their-hosts).